I cant access mysql in cli vs code(Terminal) on windows
I have to access mysql in CLI vs code(Terminal) on Windows but, I cant access.Please solve my problem.
I am doing back end development and try to use sql from cli. There is command line for mac users i.e. /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p but for windows what is the process to access mysql in cli.

your question is not very clear. you have access but you cant access it? can you describe the situation exactly and give some code examples with errors you are getting? also what is the output when you type mysql --version in the cli?

You question needs to be made more clear.
But from what I am guessing, you probably have not installed the command in the path.
Assuming you have properly installed mysql, and the service is running.
You can try this,
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
mysql -u your_username -p

You need to access the folder where the mysql binary is installed, then you can run the login command.
You can change the cd command based on where you installed mysql server.
